# Choose nodes that matches python lxml

Tags: python, python-2.7, xpath, xslt-1.0, lxml

I have the following XML example below:

```
                    <a:p>
                        <a:r>
                            <a:rPr lang="en-US" dirty="0"/>
                            <a:t>Go for a </a:t>
                        </a:r>
                        <a:r>
                            <a:rPr lang="en-US" dirty="0" smtClean="0"/>
                            <a:t>test-drive</a:t>
                        </a:r>
                        <a:r>
                            <a:rPr lang="de-DE" dirty="0" smtClean="0">
                                <a:hlinkClick r:id="rId11"/>
                            </a:rPr>
                            <a:t>http</a:t>
                        </a:r>
                        <a:r>
                            <a:rPr lang="de-DE" dirty="0">
                                <a:hlinkClick r:id="rId11"/>
                            </a:rPr>
                            <a:t>://</a:t>
                        </a:r>
                        <a:r>
                            <a:rPr lang="de-DE" dirty="0" smtClean="0">
                                <a:hlinkClick r:id="rId11"/>
                            </a:rPr>
                            <a:t>google.com</a:t>
                        </a:r>
                        <a:r>
                            <a:rPr lang="de-DE" dirty="0" smtClean="0"/>
                            <a:t>.</a:t>
                        </a:r>
                    </a:p>
```

I have to loop through all `a:r` nodes and get `text` out of the nodes without children `a:hlinkClick`.For exapmle the output should look like:

```
Go for a test drive .
```

The link has to be `exculded`. I have done the following in python to get the `link` only:

```
if d.xpath('./a:r/a:rPr[@dirty="0"]/a:hlinkClick[@r:id]',  namespaces=NAMESPACES) != []:
    e = d.xpath('./a:r/a:rPr/a:hlinkClick/../../a:t/text()',  namespaces=NAMESPACES)
    print ''.join(e)
```

But now I would want to know how I could go on to get only the text. Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about

```
>>> import re
>>> telems = d.xpath('.//a:r[not(.//a:hlinkClick)]//a:t/text()', namespaces=NAMESPACES)
>>> joined_text = ''.join(telems).strip()
>>> re.sub('\s+', ' ', joined_text)
'Go for a test-drive.'
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have an xmlObject you can iterate the object and get for each tag it's text and attributes.

I'm using Element Tree, please see the python documentation [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html)